# python import error

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

what's wrong with my imports?

App folder structure:

myapp/

- models/models.py contains `SpotModel()`
- tests/tests.py contains TestSpotModel(unittest.TestCase). tests.py imports `from myapp.models.models import *` which works like a charm
- scripts/import.py contains `from myapp.models.models import *`

the problem is that import.py when executed results in an error:

```
ImportError: No module named myapp.models.models
```

but tests.py runs.

I have `__init__.py` files in `myapp/__init__.py`, `myapp/models/__init__.py`, `myapp/tests/__init__.py` and as mentioned, running the unit tests using nosetests works as intended.

Comment: `from foo import *` is highly discouraged because it causes namespace collisions. It is hard to tell what might be happening with that statement present.

Comment: I'd also try to avoid naming a module with a Python keyword like `import`. Now you can't `import myapp.import`!

Comment: I renamed it to python myapp/scripts/data.py but it's still the same problem

Comment: @msw Within packages, `import *` is much less of a problem if one knows what they're doing, and also ubiquitous.

Comment: @Nick T: sexually transmitted diseases are ubiquitous, it doesn't mean they need an advocate. And in this instance one didn't know what one was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `__init__.py` not `init.py`. Make sure each of the directory in hierarchy contains it in order to be able to import.

**EDIT:** I managed to reproduce it.
Here's the directory structure:

```
cesar@cesar-laptop:/tmp/asdasd$ tree
.
`-- myapp
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- models
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- models.py
    |-- scripts
    |   |-- data.py
    |   `-- __init__.py
    `-- tests
        |-- __init__.py
        `-- tests.py
```

I put the following code at the very beginning of the `data.py` to narrow down the problem:

```
import sys
import pprint

pprint.pprint(sys.path)

from myapp.models.models import *
```

Running the `data.py` the way OP indicated yeilds ImportError:

```
cesar@cesar-laptop:/tmp/asdasd$ python myapp/scripts/data.py
['/tmp/asdasd/myapp/scripts',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 -- Skipped --
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp/scripts/data.py", line 6, in 
    from myapp.models.models import *
ImportError: No module named myapp.models.models
```

But this way works like a charm:

```
cesar@cesar-laptop:/tmp/asdasd$ python -m myapp.scripts.data
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 -- Skipped --
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
```

Note the difference in the first entry of `sys.path`.

Comment: He wrote `__init__.py`, but initially without backticks, so markdown thought it should display it bold.

Comment: Do I need an __init__.py inside the scripts folder as well? I tried adding it, but it's still the same error

Answer (score 1):

How are you executing `import.py`? What is the current working directory when you do so?

The `myapp` directory must be on the Python *path* (ie. inside one of the directories listed in `sys.path`) for you to be able to `import` it. Python automatically adds the current working directory to the path list at interpreter startup time.

So if the directory that contains `myapp` is not added to the path manually (eg. using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or adding it to `sys.path` in `sitecustomize.py`), you will need to be in the directory containing `myapp` when you run the script. If you're inside the `myapp` directory itself, you won't be able to import the `myapp` package.

Comment: I am executing it like this python myapp/scripts/import.py

Answer (score 1):

Your `sys.path` is clearly not set the same way when you're running the test and when you're running the script.  Do

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

at the top of both modules to confirm that.  Then, fix the one that's wrong (by appending to `sys.path` the parent directory of `myapp` in the case where it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you forgot to mention it, you don't have a `__init__.py` in `myapp/scripts`, so `myapp/scripts/import.py` is not a module of `myapp`.

Unless `myapp` is in your global path somehow, the script can't find it because it won't be looking for it in the right place.

Either make your scripts folder a module by adding a `__init__.py` to it, move the scripts up the filesystem hierarchy (either into `myapp` or into its parent folder) or install `myapp` into your path (i.e. move it to your `packages` folder, e.g. `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/`).